# Forwarding request to a content page

Tags: 8, page-controller

How can I forward a request from module to a content page?

I have got a module that authenticates users; once authenticated, the module should forward the request to a content page or node (not redirecting).

`public HttpKernel::forward($controller, array $attributes = array(), array $query = array())` allows to forward the request to a controller.

How do I forward the request to, for example, http://localhost:8080/techlab/evaluations, where *evaluations* is a created article?

Answer (score 0):

You return a RedirectResponse() with the path. If you're in a controller, you can use the `redirect()` method from ControllerBase.

Comment: As I mentioned , I'm not after RedirectResponse.

Because, redirect will force browser to make a request. 

Instead , after authenticating ,  the module should forward the request to an article created.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a class method to perform the forwarding.

```
class HttpUtil {

    /**
     * Use in controller method:
     *  // ....
     *  return HttpUtil::forward('/alias');
     *
     * @param $path
     * @param string $method
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public static function forward($path, $method='GET') {
      $lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasStorage $aliasStorage */
      $aliasStorage = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage');
      $internalUri = $aliasStorage->lookupPathSource($path, $lang);

      /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request */
      $request = \Drupal::request();

      $subRequest = \Drupal::request()->create(
        $internalUri,
        $method,
        $request->query->all(),
        $request->cookies->all(),
        $request->files->all(),
        $request->server->all()
      );

      /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel $kernel */
      $httpKernel = \Drupal::service('http_kernel.basic');

      /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $subResponse */
      $subResponse = $httpKernel->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);

      return $subResponse;
    }

    // ...
}
```